# java process memory increase with new Strings and byte[] created?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, gzip, heap-memory

We added a new feature in our web application that has the the following code, basically decompressing the inputstream and creating a new String with UTF-8 encoding

```
....
// is is an instance of java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
byte[] payloadBuf = org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
String plainPayload = new String(payloadBuf, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
...
```

when we run an intensive load test that triggers this path many times, we see an abnormal increase of not-heap memory in JVM. Can anyone give some hint on interpreting this? And even better, is there a way to avoid it somehow? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

#### There is nothing abnormal about your results:

If you call this code in a tight loop you are creating lots and lots of short lived objects. 3 `byte[]` instances ( all `Objects` ) as well as a `ByteArrayStream` for every call! And for no reason apparently.

So you are creating and copying a bunch of `byte[]` instances around and then the `String` constructor creates at least one more `byte[]` and copies that as well, all for nothing.

#### Are not accomplishing what you think you are doing:

You are **not** *creating a new String with UTF-8 encoding*, you are creating a new `String` which is interpreting the `byte[]` as `UTF-8`.

Java stores **all** `String` objects in memory as `UTF-16`, so you are not *creating a new String with UTF-8 encoding*.

#### Solution:

You should just read the file into a `String` to begin with and be done with it, you are creating this intermediate `byte[]` for nothing!

Here is a couple of examples using Guava:

```
final String text = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(is,Charsets.UTF_8));
```

or

```
final ByteSource source ...
final String text = source.asCharSource(Charsets.UTF_8).read();
```

#### Opinion:

That `org.apache.commmons` stuff is crap with all the cancerous dependencies and it is not doing anything special to begin with and still makes you deal with a checked exception on top of it all!

```
165    public static byte[] toByteArray(final InputStream input) throws IOException {
166        final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
167        copy(input, output);
168        return output.toByteArray();
169    }
```

If you follow the rabbit hole you will find out that one call to `.toByteArray()` creates at least 3 instances of `byte[]` objects, a couple of `ByteArrayStream` objects that all end up as garbage just to get to `String`.

Comment: THank you for the comment, Jarrod. Really appreciate it. If what I really need is the byte[], then I should use      byte[] payloadBuf = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);    and remove the reference of the String, as I only need it once for checking something?